# How can I set myself as owner of a database ? just using sql

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

As I want to view dependencies of just a couple of tables in my clients database I want to set myself as the owner of the database.

If the database is called MyDatabase and my userName is MyDomain\MyUserName
How do I use the ALTER AUTHORIZATION statement to set myself as Owner ?

Comment: Maybe something like ALTER AUTHORIZATION ON DATABASE::MyDatabase TO MyLoginUser;

Comment: If it is your client's database, I doubt if you will have the permissions to set yourself as the `DBO`. This action requires `TAKE OWNERSHIP` permission on the entity.

Comment: @Raj I am sorry you feel that way. But I am just asking how to do it not if I should do it why I am doing it. FYI I am asked by the client to do it

Comment: Can the one who downvoted please let me know why he downvoted ?

Comment: OK. Both answers posted below should work, since they have mentioned nothing about permissions, thought I would alert you. BTW, I did not down vote.

Answer (score 1):

Check this links and references:
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178630.aspx

Example:

```
EXEC sp_changedbowner 'Albert'
```

and `ALTER AUTHORIZATION`

```
ALTER AUTHORIZATION ON OBJECT::Parts.Sprockets TO MichikoOsada;
GO
```

[http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187359(v=sql.105).aspx](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187359%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

Comment: I tried both and they both work

Comment: DId the sql server return any message when you execute it?

Comment: Both statements work and yield Command(s) completed successfully.

Comment: Wich Sql Version is?

Answer (score 0):

ALTER AUTHORIZATION ON DATABASE::MyDatabase TO MyUserName;